# Dell Venue 8 Pro: why is the battery designed to charge up to 87%

Tags: battery, tablet

I noticed that my Dell Venue 8 Pro (Windows 8.1) battery does not charge more than 87%.

So I uninstalled the ACPI-compliant control method. It reinstalled automatically on reboot.

The charge was now caping at 96%. But wasn't getting to 100%.

So I ran the Dell PC-doctor diagnostic. The battery passed the test. But in the report, it says that the battery is designed to charge up to 87%....

So why isn't it designed to charge up to 100%?

Answer (score 1):

The battery life is greater if it's charged to a bit less than 100%. Oversimplifying a bit -- the more charge the battery already has, the more work it takes to cram more charge into it. Charging to a level of 85%-90%, rather than 100%, avoids the portion of the charge cycle that most reduces the battery's life.

You can leave a modern battery on charge all the time an external power source is available without significantly affecting battery life. (Ignore any advice you hear about trying to fully discharge it before charging it.) So it isn't that important to get the last little bit of charge into it.

Usually the manufacturer provides a way to adjust the charge level. The option is usually called something like "battery life extender".